# how to add a string after @var in razor engine (ASP MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string, razor

i have a problem with my code in a ASP MVC app.

I use the razor engine to write a var like:

```
@var
```

but now i need to add some text directly after the var:

```
@varMyText
```

but this is not working, only with a whitespace:

```
@var MyText
```

how to make this without a whitespace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That'd be

```
@(var)MyText
```

Or

```
@(var + "MyText")
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
@string.Format("{0}MyText", variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use any of [HtmlHelpers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for example [Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
@Html.Raw("Your string");
```